# Ratio "observed-to-expected" - how do you call it?

Tags: error, terminology

Is there a *name* for the ratio of the observed count in a cell (say, ij) to the expected count in it - $O_{ij}/E_{ij}$? Likelihood ratio Chi-square (= G-square) statistic is based on these quantities. And is there a general name for the ratio-type form of a "residual" or an "unfit" in statistics?

Comment: In epidemiology, when talking about deaths, this is called the standardized mortality ratio or when talking about disease standardized incidence ratio.

Comment: On the contrary, the $\chi^2$ statistic is based on $(O-E)^2/E$, which cannot be determined from $O/E$ alone.  The latter is, however, directly obtainable from the *relative error* $(O-E)/E = O/E-1$ and from the *log residual* $\log(O)-\log(E) = \log(O/E)$.

Comment: @whuber, I didn’t claim that it could be computed on the _ratio alone_, without knowing the observed frequencies. Pearson Chi-square is $\Sigma\Sigma[(O−E)^2 /E]=\Sigma\Sigma [O \frac{O}{E} ]−N$. So it can be computed with the help of the ratio. However, in the question I mentioned LR Chi-square which is also computed with the help of the ratio. The question is about whether the ratio bears some established _name_.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> In epidemiology, when talking about deaths, this is called the
>   standardized mortality ratio or when talking about disease
>   standardized incidence ratio.

– StatsStudent

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of observed to expected counts does not need to be called anything other than what it is. In a proportional error system, $\frac{O}{E}-1$ in a cell is also the measurement error in that cell, and for different error systems, it would have different meanings.